NiceGUI element deletion
When I create a NiceGUI element such as a ui.label or ui.select item, is it proper to use the .delete() method? Or what would be the best way to remove it. I'll include an example
class SpeakerLayout(ui.row):
    def __init__(self, workbench, lang_code=None, name=None, region=None, voice=None, gender=Gender.DEFAULT_VOICE):
        super().__init__()

        self.workbench = workbench
        self.which_tts = self.workbench.which_tts
        self.tts = TextToSpeech(self.workbench)
        self.tts.get_token()
        self.sample_sentence = "We all love a good story. Adventure, peril, heroes vanquishing evil."
        self.play_obj = None

        self.lang_code = lang_code
        self.name = name
        self.region = region
        self.voice = voice
        self.gender = gender

        self.translator = Translator(self.workbench)

        with self:
            self.name_label = ui.label(self.name)
            self.region_box = ui.select(options=[], on_change=self.region_change)
            self.voice_box = ui.select(options=[], on_change=self.voice_change)
            self.voice_sample = ui.button("Voice Sample", on_click=self.play_voice_sample)

        self.region_code = None
        self.voice_idx = 0

        self.set_region_items()
        self.region_change(0)

    def delete_layout(self):
        self.name_label.delete()
        self.region_box.delete()
        self.voice_box.delete()
        self.voice_sample.delete()

I have tried this method before and I'm aware of the clear function. Would that be better?
